# How to ensure counter integrity across loadbalanced azure functions?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-function-app

I am using azure functions and CosmosDB as the DB backend, and I am trying to figure out how I can ensure a counter integrity across load balanced functions.

For example CosmosDB has a document with a property "QueueNumber" : 1

now I need to fetch the number in that series which is "QueueNumber" : 2

But my application is load balanced across multiple function app and even within a single function app how do I ensure the integrity of that counter ?

in a single app using statics or voilitile properties seems to work but how do I do it across multiple function apps?

Answer (score 0):

You could for example use a Blob on a Storage Account and uses [Leases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467010/what-is-azure-lease-blob). Any Function needs to acquire a Lease first before it reads (and updates) the value in the blob (or in your Cosmos document). If the blob is currently locked, have your Function wait and try again.

Comment: Ok so each function would check for lease, if ok read and update , then release lease, and all other functions would check and wait during that time, sounds like a queueing system, is there no queue service that can do do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Monotonically increasing numeric id's require something akin to a distributed mutex.

One option is to use [Service Fabric Reliable Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections).