# Azure web app - how to avoid multiple users triggering the same endpoint at time

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

Is there any way to set a limit on the number of requests for the azure web app (asp.net web API)?
I have an endpoint that runs for a long time and I like to avoid multiple triggers while the application is processing one request.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This would have to be a custom implementation which can be done in a few ways

**1. Leverage a Queue**
This involves separating the background process into a separate execution flow by using a queue. So, your code would be split up into two parts

- API Endpoint that receives the request and inserts a message into a queue
- Separate Method (or Service) that listens on the queue and processes messages one by one

The second method could either be in the same Web App or could be separated into a Function App. The queue could be in [Azure Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview), which your Web App or Function would be listening in on.

This approach has the added benefits of durability since if the web app or function were to crash and you would like to ensure that requests are all processed, the message would be processed again in order if not completed on the queue.

**2. Distributed Lock**
This approach is simpler but lacks durability. Here you would simply use an in-memory queue to process requests but ensure only one is being processed at a time but having the method acquire a lock which the following requests would wait for before being processed.

You could leverage [blob storage leases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44468821/10417839) as a option for distributed locks.